# Trouble scraping Data Attributes with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on a simple `web scraping` project using a page from finish line.
I am trying to scrape the site for product names, brands and pricing to export into a neat csv file.

Here is an example of the html code that I am trying to scrape

```
<div class="product-card" id="itemprod797157_128" data-brand="NIKE" data-prodid="prod797157" data-productid="prod797157553558128" data-baseurl="/store/product/mens-air-jordan-retro-1-low-basketball-shoes/prod797157?" data-colordescription="White/Black/Starfish" data-styleid="553558" data-colorid="128">
```

I am wanting to scrape the `data-brand` attribute, but am having some issues.

here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36'
}
data2 = requests.get("https://www.finishline.com/store/men/shoes/casual/_/N-1q3xsyk?icid=LP_mgl_C_menslpcategorycasualshoes_PDCT",headers=headers)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(data2.text, 'html.parser')

main_column = soup2.find(id="mainColumn")

products = main_column.find_all(class_='product-card')

price = main_column.find_all(class_='fullPrice')

name = main_column.find_all(class_='product-name')

brand = [item['data-brand'] for item in main_column.find_all('class', attrs={'data-brand' : True})]

print(brand)
```

my code returns `[]`

**How can I scrape the specific data-brand attribute?**

Answer (score 0):

I gotta say that I'm a total beginner and I can't explain why this line doesn't work:

```
brand = [item['data-brand'] for item in main_column.find_all('class', attrs={'data-brand' : True})]
```

but I tried finding the class "product-card" and then selected the 'data-brand' from the attrs list like this:

```
brands = [item.attrs['data-brand'] for item in main_column.find_all(class_="product-card")]
```

This returns:

```
['NIKE', 'NIKE', 'NIKE', 'ADIDAS', 'NIKE', 'ADIDAS', 'NIKE', 'NIKE', 'NIKE', 'NIKE', 'NIKE', 'NIKE']
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I'm very much a beginner as well, kinda exploring scraping for fun and experimenting. I appreciate your comment!

Comment: Could you please mark my answer as the best solution? If a better answer comes along you can select that as the best one.